# GPS and SensorManager values should update camera preview

Tags: android, service, gps, android-sensors

Hi everyone
I wish to update my camera preview whenever there is a change in GPSlocation and Sensor Manager values, i am currently using two services for this purpose,but i am not able to receive the updates on my preview. Is it possible to combine these services into one and then use intents and broadcastReceivers? or any alternative is present?
Please guide me on this 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use just one `Service` to keep track of GPS and Sensor data and use a `ResultReceiver` or `Messenger` and `Message` to pass back updates to the `Handler` in your `Activity`.

Edit:

Sorry, forgot to mention that you pass the `ResultReceiver` or `Message` as a parcelable extra in the `Intent` you use to start the `Service`.

Comment: Thanks but how should i update my camera preview with this message?

Comment: @Nidhi:  You will need to overlay another view on the top of the camera preview. This view will probably need to be a `SurfaceView` or `GLSurfaceView` but could just be a layout of `ImageViews` depending on the desirde effect.  For an example of how to use a `SurfaceView` have a look at the LunarLander SDK sample.